# How to detect the two tabs in a string in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading data form tab separated file:

```
str1 = '1  3'
str2 = '4 5 6'
```

In **'str1'** second place is empty. I am reading line by line in matlab and then using strsplit, I extract  values from each line and later, I am building arrays. Each column in text correspond to each array.

```
strsplit(str1, '\t')
yeilds ==> '1 3'
strsplit(str2, '\t')
yeilds ==> '4 5 6'
```

Somehow, I miss that second place in first string is empty. How can I save this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has built-in support to read tab-separated files:

```
A = importdata('file.txt', '\t')
```

If your file looks like this:

```
1\t2\t3
4\t\t5
```

`importdata` yields:

```
A =

    1     2     3
    4   NaN     5
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for this kind of functionality

Answer (score 3):

Try using a regular expression:

```
str1 = '1  3'

numel(regexp(str1, '\t'))  % look for the number of elements of the regular expression that looks for tabs '\t'
```

will return `2`

For your problem you could do the following:

```
tmp = regexp(str1, '(\d*)\t(\d*)\t(\d*)', 'tokens')

tmp{1} 
        = 
        '1' '' '3'
```

Comment: I do not know why I getting 0 and could you explain your solution as well.

Comment: I should do so, however, what do you know about regular expressions?